# How to know if a process is open in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-handling

I have code that increases the identification of a user.  What I need is two processes that run at the same time.  If one process has already entered, the other enters a loop to know if it can enter.  How do I know if I already have the txt file open so I can enter the wait cycle.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use `handle.exe` by [sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to see the handles to a particular file and which processes is using the file. Once you get the PID , you can wait for it to complete.